# GRE sample exam problem 47 page 44

Tags: real-analysis, gre-exam

This question is from the GRE sample exam found at https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_math.pdf
It is from page 44 of the pdf, problem 47. The problem reads,

The function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as follows:

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}3x^2 \textrm{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q}
\\
-5x^2 \textrm{ if } x \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{matrix}\right.$

Which of the following is true?

(A) $f$ is discontinuous at all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

(B) $f$ is continuous only at $x=0$ and differentiable only at $x=0$.

(C)$f$ is continuous only at $x=0$ and nondifferentiable at all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

(D)$f$ is continuous at all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and nondifferentiable at all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

(E)$f$ is continuous at all $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and nondifferentiable at all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I do not know what the correct answer is, but I have done some thinking and would appreciate input from the community. First, Both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, which I think makes it impossible to say that the function is continuous anywhere save the point of intersection, $x=0$. This thinking still seems wrong to me because discontinuities exist in the neighborhood about $x=0$. If this thinking is still (somehow) correct, then since a function is only differentiable where it is continuous, the answer could be (B)?

I'm not understanding the critical definitions here. Can somebody quickly fill-me in on what I need to understand for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: You haven't ruled out (C). A function can be continuous but non-differentiable.

Comment: Because of the infinitely-many discontinuities in the neighborhood of $x=0$?

Comment: Well, that would be one thing, but even a nice, everywhere continuous function like $|x|$ fails to be differentiable at $x = 0$. There are more pathological examples of [everywhere-continuous-but-nowhere-differentiable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) out there as well. In short, you can't tell just from continuity that the function is differentiable.

Comment: No idea why I claimed R\Q was dense in R, that makes no sense, because it implies Z is dense in R, which it certainly is not

Comment: It definitely makes sense, and it does not imply that $\Bbb Z$ is sense in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in this case, but as Arthur says in the comments you haven't really justified why it is B and not C.

The function is not continuous (and hence not differentiable) anywhere that $3x^2\neq-5x^2$, since for any $x$ you can get sequence of rationals $x_i\to x$ and a sequence of irrationals $y_i\to x$, so $\lim f(x_i)=3x^2$ but $\lim f(y_i)=-5x^2$.

It is continuous at $0$, because for any sequence $z_i\to 0$ the subsequence of rational $z_j$ has $f(z_j)\to 0$, the same is true for the irrational subsequence, and between them, these cover the whole sequence.

It is also differentiable at $0$, but that only works because not only do $3x^2$ and $-5x^2$ coincide at $0$, but also their derivatives coincide at $0$. (If your functions were $3x$ and $-5x$, it would be nowhere-differentiable, but still continuous at $0$.)

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense